# No sound from external speakers after installing new monitor

Tags: audio, external-display

I just installed a Samsung chg90 49" curved monitor. When hooking it up, I had to use an hdmi from the monitor to a DVI port on the computer because my HDMI port doesn't work on the computer.

After hooking this up, I am not getting any sound from my external speakers. I checked to make sure the audio wire was still connected and it is. I tried checking for sound options in the monitor settings and the only sound option I saw was for a microphone.

Does anyone know what I could look for or have any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As standard, DVI does not include an audio stream: see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#DVI_and_HDMI_compatibility).

Comment: @AFH I have audio hooked up to the speaker connections. I had this exact same audio connection an hour ago. My previous monitor was DVI to DVI. I'm not trying to get sound from the monitor.

Comment: Do you not have a DVI port on the new monitor? Or HDMI on the old? If so, try mixing and matching monitors and cables. Also, start an audio stream, then unplug the new monitor, trying each end of the cable in turn, to see if sound is restored.. It would help to know what OS you're running.

Comment: @AFH I am running Windows 10. There is no DVI port on the new monitor. Here is the link to it. https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B072C7TNC5/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1 .... There is an HDMI port on the old monitor, but I always just used a DVI to DVI connection.

Comment: It's worth trying HDMI on the old monitor, to see if this mutes the sound. Maybe your graphics card has the audio extension on the DVI (as per my link above), and tries to send it over the HDMI cable.

Comment: @AFH Just tried it. The sound is muted as well on the old monitor. Why would this be though if it is routing to the DVI? Anything I could do?

Comment: Control Panel / Sound - What devices do you have listed?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas Just added what is listed to my question in an img.

Comment: Your audio devices list shows that the system is trying to output to speakers on the new monitor. You could look at the audio devices in Device Manager and, if there is one that looks like HDMI sound, disable or remove it. I need to go to bed now, as it has gone midnight here, but I'll check in the morning if you have made progress.

Comment: @AFH Thanks. I posted another screen shot in my question. Not sure if any of those options are what you are referring to.

Comment: I figured it out. See the answer below.

Comment: Glad it's sorted. I'm still more used to the control panel settings than the Win10 system settings.

Answer (score 0):

After going into the sound settings, I changed the device properties and it worked!

[image]